# Form "is undefined" error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this code, let say it's `a.html`

```
<form name="frmSubmit" id="frmSubmit" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="hdnName" value="user name" />
</form>

<script>
// 1 : start
document.frmSubmit.action = 'b.html';
document.frmSubmit.submit();
// 1 : end

// 2 : start
document.getElementById("frmSubmit").action = 'b.html';
document.getElementById("frmSubmit").submit();
// 2 : end
</script>
```

Both **1** and **2** are working in IE (IE 8), but not in FF (3.6.10). Firebug gives me the following error:

> document.frmSubmit is undefined

How can I fix it?

Comment: Both methods should work fine (and do, for me).  I suspect your error lies somewhere else and this isn't a true representation of the code you have.  See http://jsfiddle.net/VL8C3/, I replaced your methods with simple console outputs so you can see `document.frmSubmit` *is* defined.

Comment: is it a <form> has to inside <body>? or it's a bugs? I tried to add simple <p>abcd</p> before <form>, and it's work :D

Comment: @Andy: the script exactly same as above script

Comment: What error does Firebug give you for method 2? I take it you don't really have both 1 and 2 in the same script block at the same time, in which case an error in 1 may prevent it even getting to 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function setup(){
// 1 : start
document.frmSubmit.action = 'b.html';
document.frmSubmit.submit();
// 1 : end

// 2 : start
document.getElementById("frmSubmit").action = 'b.html';
document.getElementById("frmSubmit").submit();
// 2 : end
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setup()">
<form name="frmSubmit" id="frmSubmit" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="hdnName" value="user name" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <p>abcd</p><form> .... it's works, or <br><form> ... it's works to, it's seem I have to add another tag before <form> to make it works

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when I'm going to code those workarrounds, to avoid an error to halt the execution, I surround conflicting blocks with try&cathc.
I would recommend surrounding **1** and **2** with try/catch bloks, so it there is an error there, it does not halt script execution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and managed to get it to work by doing the following:

- Have a imagebutton or any other type of postback object on your form which displays what you want ("buy now!")
- Have an event in codebehind for when this was clicked.
- On click of the event, do a response.redirect to a new page you will create (postpaypal.aspx).
- Create new file (postpaypal.aspx), which doesn't use a master page, has it's own form and the standard paypal code and actions.

This worked beautifully for me, and was simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have given,
input type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed"

Instead of it , name should be like this
input type="submit" name="sub" value="Proceed"

NB: name should be other than "submit"